# Is the setup-punchline relation equivalent to a question-answer one?

Tags: questions, philosophy-of-humor

**Philosophical relevance:** there are an [SEP entry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/humor/) and an [IEP entry](https://iep.utm.edu/humor/) on humor. Now, it has often seemed to me that there is something about saying that life is a Test that is akin to saying that life is a Joke (a good one, that is). And saying that life is a Game besides; but so now is the relation between a joke's setup and its punchline then akin to the relation between a question and an answer? As if the setup is a puzzle, and the humorousness is not in some mere incongruity of the solution, but something more like the *congruent incongruity* of the thing?

Or should we say that understanding an answer to a question is more than knowing it, like how understanding a punchline is more than knowing it: to get a joke is to understand it? Modulo the incongruity thesis, say, getting a joke is appreciating a "funny" answer to a question, where the funniness is a function of understanding how the answer is incongruous?

Comment: My opinion is that humor comes from creating stress, then creating a surprise that is not dangerous to the audience and which resolves the stress. A joke is a unit of stress-surprise-safety.

Comment: @gs I need not deny that, ultimately. What I would then look for an erotetic analysis of was the surprised-by relation, where, "It is surprising that..." goes with the matter of the joke, i.e. the punchline is a non-dangerous surprise.

Comment: Isn't the mark of a (genuine) question that the answer is not known when it is asked? A joke, on the other hand, is designed to lead up to the punchline. If there is an analogy it is to a rhetorical question. That is also designed to lead up to the "answer" and in a theatrical sort of way.

Comment: @Conifold what about coming up with a joke in the first place? For a simplified example, memes with upper and lower text might be hard to design: you start with the background and the theme, write the upper line, then have to figure out what lower text matches the background and the upper line, and this might be more of a genuine-question process?